# Affinity Mask Setting Error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We were just trying to move a couple of CPU from one instance to another in the processor page of the properties. The instance we were moving them from was sql server 16 and the one they were going to was 19.

So we added them to 19 first. We've found overlapping CPU in our environment before so we didn't think it would matter which way round it was done.

When we tried to remove the CPU from the 16 instance we got the following error

> an item with the same key has already been added. (mscorlib)

Can't seem to find much online about it but sort of looks like it might be a bug in ssms?

Anyone out there seen this?